# Replacing use of a library with a wrapper library

Tags: c++, refactoring

We have a C++ solution (VC++ 2005) which makes extensive use of of a 3rd-party mapping library. We are creating wrapper libraries so that we can use alternative mapping libraries in our solution without having to rewrite it for each - each wrapper library having the same API but wrapping a different 3rd-party mapping library.

We're doing this in an iterative way and I am wondering how we can ensure that as we refactor classes from using a specific mapping lib to using the wrapper, all uses/references are updated. By definition many of the wrapper classes are interoperable with the wrapped library classes so we could easily miss updating one instance of MapXYZ::Attribute to OurMaps::Attribute and it would all work until we switched mapping libs.

Are there any tools or processes that can be advised for such a scenario?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, if the wrappers are interoperable with the wrapped classes that does not mean they are *exchangeable*. So to make sure you don't accidentally use classes of the original lib, just delete any `#include` referring to their headers. Your compiler will complain about any use of original classes and their members. Note: you won't have those heaers included in your wrapper lib's headers, or else the abstraction would be leaking and replacing the current library would be impossible.

In addition, for your wrapper you should not stick too closely to the API of the library you have been using, because other libraries might not provide similar methods and attributes. Instead, define the wrapper API based on the basic concepts *you use* and that any library you might use in the future will have to offer one way or another. That means, the API should not resemble what one specific third party library offers, instead it should show what you need. In other words, the API provides the verbs and nouns of *your* language, describing the problem domain the way *you* think of it, and the wrapper classes will translate that into the language of the wrapped library.
That way you will have a clean abstraction of the mapping libraries in your code, although you will have to refactor it, ironing out the cranks and bolts you had to use to make the third party lib work, instead of just replacing `class ThirdPartyX` by `class MyWrapperX`.

Comment: How can a specific implementation of the wrapper library targeting wrapped library X _not_ include X's headers? e.g. if I was writing two wrapper libs around STL and Win32, the STL version would have to include stl headers or it wouldn't compile?

Comment: read carefully - I did not say it should not include the wrapped lib's headers *at all*, I said it should not include them *in its headers*. Of course you will have to include them in the sources, but including it in the header means, you include them indirectly in the rest of your project, removing the major benefit your wrapper class gives: encapsulation.